# broken packages error while trying to install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, xorg

I'm new to Linux and I'm a mac user. I'm now having a problem when i try to install "mtrack" to "fix" my macbook pro 8,1 trackpad. My ubuntu is on version 14.04 currently and i got this error message when i try to install mtrack from BlueDragonX.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-mtrack : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I hope you guys can help me on this. Thanks alot!

Comment: Have already tried: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I tried but it is still showing the same error

Comment: what additional repositories you have installed

Comment: i just installed my ubuntu 14.04 and there is no other repositories in it

Comment: Post the output of: apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-input-mtrack

Answer (score 2):

I just checked out that `xorg-input-abi-20` is  present in other packages `xserver-xorg-core-udeb` and `xserver-xorg-core`

So try to install `xserver-xorg-core` manually,

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

and then install `mtrack`